# Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find '<method>' in 'window'

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

oof what a day, trying to figure out dynamically injecting sdk.js and create button tag with src = some url.

I have added all my js code into a file  scripting to inject sdk based on params and kept under wwwroot, but for somereason my function is not able detect by server.js

Exception that am getting is -
**Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'initializeSDK' in 'window'.**

here's the js code i have

```
    window.initializeSDK = {

    ejectInjectSdk: function (action, environment) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        if (action == "inject") {
            if (self === top) {
                var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
                antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
            } else {
                top.location = self.location;
            }


            if (environment == 'Sandbox') {

                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = "https://sandbox-assets.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/integration/v1/sdk.js";
                document.body.append(script);
            } else if (environment == 'live') {
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = "https://assets.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/integration/v1/sdk.js";
                document.body.append(script);
            }

        } else if (action == "eject") {
            if (environment == 'Sandbox') {
                $("script[src='https://sandbox-assets.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/integration/v1/sdk.js']").remove();
            } else if (environment == 'live') {
                $("script[src='https://assets.secure.checkout.visa.com/checkout-widget/resources/js/integration/v1/sdk.js']").remove();
            }

        }
        $("#vcoholder").hide();
    },

    ejectInjectBtn: function (initpayload) {
        $("#vcoholder").append("<img alt='Visa Checkout' class='v-button' role='button' src='https://sandbox.secure.checkout.visa.com/wallet-services-web/xo/button.png' />");
        onVisaCheckoutReady(initpayload);
        $("#vcoholder").show();

    },

    onVisaCheckoutReady: function (initpayload) {

        console.log(initpayload);
        V.init(initpayload);
        V.on("payment.success", function (payment) {
            console.log(payment);
            var obj = {};
            obj.isLive = false;
            obj.apikey = $.trim($("#apikey").val());
            obj.sharedsecretkey = $.trim($("#sharedsecretkey").val());
            obj.encapikey = $.trim($("#encapikey").val());
            obj.encsharedsecretkey = $.trim($("#encsharedsecretkey").val());
            obj.encKey = payment.encKey;
            obj.encPaymentData = payment.encPaymentData;
            obj.vInitRequest = payment.vInitRequest;
            obj.callid = payment.callid;

            console.log("Payload sending to server " + JSON.stringify(obj));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '../api/Restful/Getresultsv2',
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $("#displayJson").jsonViewer(result, {
                        collapsed: false,
                        withQuotes: true
                    })
                }
            });

        });
        V.on("payment.cancel", function (payment) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
        });
        V.on("payment.error", function (payment, error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
};
```

And complete razor page below-

```
@page "/ClicktoPay"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Zapy.Server.ViewModels
@using Zapy.Server.Servcies
@using Zapy.Server.Models.Clicktopay;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@inject CheckoutService Checkoutservice
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration


<h3>Component1</h3>

<div id="nonsegmentedkeys" class="row">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="height: 560px;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <EditForm Model="@clicktoPayViewModel">
                    <div id="segmentedkeys">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="encryptionapikey">Encryption's Apikey</label>
                            <InputText class="form-control form-control-sm" id="encryptionapikey" @bind-Value="clicktoPayViewModel.EncryptionKey" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="encryptionsharedsecretkey">Encryptions's Sharedsecret</label>
                            <InputText class="form-control form-control-sm" id="encryptionsharedsecretkey" @bind-Value="clicktoPayViewModel.EncryptionSharedsecret" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label for="inboundapikey">Inbound Apikey</label>
                            <InputText class="form-control form-control-sm" id="inboundapikey" @bind-Value="clicktoPayViewModel.InboundApikey" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inboundsharedsecret">Inbound Sharedsecret</label>
                            <InputText class="form-control form-control-sm" id="inboundsharedsecret" @bind-Value="clicktoPayViewModel.InboundSharedsecret" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </EditForm>
                <div id="vcoholder">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateClicktopay">Initialize ClicktoPay</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Initialize parameters here</h5>
                <textarea id="displayJson" value="@clicktoPayViewModel.InitParameters" style="width: 550px; height: 480px;" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


@code {
    private ClicktoPayViewModel clicktoPayViewModel = new ClicktoPayViewModel();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        clicktoPayViewModel = await Checkoutservice.GetClicktoPayDefaultAsync();

    }

    public async Task CreateClicktopay()
    {

        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeSDK.ejectInjectSdk", "inject", "Sandbox");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeSDK.ejectInjectBtn", clicktoPayViewModel.InitParameters);

    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like including the js file failed. You didn't post the cshtml where that happens. Open the F12 tools and look for 404s first.

Comment: my bad, found out that there's a special character in the JS file. it took a while to find out this..lol.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you again, just corrected the js file, i'll update .razor file to in the main post.

Comment: It's not clear if you still hgave a problem. Post a self-answer if you have fixed it. Otherwise post the cshtml (the  _Host.cshtml file).

Comment: I managed to call the JS function but stll not able to register the thridparty SDK function, blazor still not able to read V.on. Let me explore and further troubleshoot the issue. I'll postback the answer once I found the solution.

Comment: is it possible that the js code hasn't been loaded that time? we have words [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering) `Where JSRuntime.InvokeAsync is called, the ElementReference is only used in OnAfterRenderAsync and not in any earlier lifecycle method because there's no JS element until after the component is rendered.` So that the `InvokeVoidAsync` should be put in `OnAfterRenderAsync`

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if you are still troubled by this.

But i also stumbled upon similar problem, where i already declared my script inside the enclosing `<body>` of `_Layout.cshtml` (I'm on Blazor Server), but i can't invoke it, the error said 'not defined'.

So what i do is basically [JS Isolation (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules) :

1. put the said script inside a separate .js file, export the functions
2. Prepare an `IJSObjectReference` as a C# object reference.
3. Inside your component's `@code` or component's code-behind class, override `OnAfterRenderAsync()`, check if it is `firstRender`. It needs to be inside OnAfterRender or OnInitialized, async or not, because in Blazor (server at least) `@inject`-ed or `[Inject]`-ed object only available, at least after the component is rendered.
4. load your .js script into the JS object reference using the injected `IJSRuntime`.
5. Then you can use it in the scope of that current component.

Here is the minimum example i can muster out

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;
@inject IJSRuntime jsInvoker
@page "/ThePage"

<h1>Hello<h1>
<Button @onClick=Consoom>Text</Button>

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? jsModule;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            jsModule = await jsInvoker.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./script/CWriter.js");
        }
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
    private async Task<bool> Consoom() {
        await jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("someFunc", "someArgs");
    }
}
```

This works for me, and i am on Blazor Server w/ .NET 6.

there's a thing to note, `IJSObjectReference` has `DisposeAsync()` but no synchronous, the usual, `Dispose()` , so you have to mind about its life-cycle too, maybe make your component also implement `IAsyncDisposable`.

Answer (score 2):

Something to keep in mind is the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0), although I was following it I did not notice that I was reading the ASP Core 6.0 documentation instead of ASP Core 5.0, in the top left menu you can select this. In my case for ASP Core 5.0 it should be noted that `<script>` should go in `_Host.cshtml` and in ASP Core 6.0 `<script>` goes in `_Layoult.cshtml`

[image]

Comment: This was it for me. Even though I had ASP.NET Core 5.0 selected in the documentation it said to put the <script> in _Layout.cshtml when calling from inside OnAfterRenderAsync().